# How do I replace a SSN with a 9 digit random number in SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

To satisfy security requirements, I need to find a way to replace [SSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number)'s with unique, random 9 digit numbers, before providing said database to a developer.  The SSN is in a column in a table of a database.  There may be 10's of thousands of rows in said table. The number does not need hyphens.  I am a beginner with SQL and programming in general.

I have been unable to find a solution for my specific needs.  Nothing seems quite right.  But if you know of a thread that I have missed, please let me know.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please show us your table structure (relevant field names and data types)

Comment: Is the expectation that the developer will be able to decrypt the random number back into the correct SSN? Or is the random number just a unique ID to identify the user?

Comment: In this case, there isn't a need to have the SSN - it is a unique ID. Providing the db to the developer is for testing/debugging purposes, so the database has to function but unless necessary, the SSN (and possibly other PII) has to be edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way.

I'm assuming that you already have a backup of the real data as this update is not reversible.

Below I've assumed your table name is **Person** with your ssn column named **SSN**.

```
UPDATE Person SET 
SSN = CAST(LEFT(CAST(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() as BINARY(10)) as int)) as varchar(max)) + '00000000',9) as int)
```

Comment: Worked great.  I hope the result satisfies the requirements, but it looks good and super easy.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If they do not have to be random, you could just replace them with ascending numeric values. Failing that, you’d have to generate a random number. As you may have discovered, the RAND function will only generate a single value per query statement (select, update, etc.); the work-around to that is the newid() function, which would generate a GUID for each row produced by a query (run `SELECT newid() from MyTable` to see how this works). Wrap this in a checksum() to generate an integer; modulus that by 1,000,00,000 to get a value within the SSN range (0 to 999,999,999); and, assuming you’re storing it as a char(9) prefix it with leading zeros.

Next trick is ensuring it’s unique for all values in your table. This gets tricky, and I’d do it by setting up a temp table with the values, populating it, then copying them over. Lessee now…

```
DECLARE @DummySSN as table
 (
   PrimaryKey  int      not null
  ,NewSSN      char(9)  not null
 )


--  Load initial values
INSERT @DummySSN 
 select
   UserId
  ,right('000000000' + cast(abs(checksum(newid()))%1000000000 as varchar(9)), 9)
 from Users

--  Check for dups
select NewSSN from @DummySSN group by NewSSN having count(*) > 1

--  Loop until values are unique
IF exists (SELECT 1 from @DummySSN group by NewSSN having count(*) > 1)
    UPDATE @DummySSN
     set NewSSN = right('000000000' + cast(abs(checksum(newid()))%1000000000 as varchar(9)), 9)
     where NewSSN in (select NewSSN from @DummySSN group by NewSSN having count(*) > 1)

--  Check for dups
select NewSSN from @DummySSN group by NewSSN having count(*) > 1
```

This works for a small table I have, and it should work for a large one. I don’t see this turning into an infinite loop, but even so you might want to add a check to exit the loop after say 10 iterations,

Comment: This assumes SSN is a unique column in the table. Duplicates (two rows for one individual) would require additional processing.

Comment: `RAND` function *can* generate different values per row, assuming you seed it `SELECT RAND(num) AS orly FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 500000) D(num);`

Comment: Good to know. Could work here if there's a unique surrogate key in the source table (such as, say, the SSN). Security purists might consider it a possible breach, since you could probably reverse-engineer the original value from the generated value.

Answer (score 0):

I've run a couple million tests in this and it seems to generate random (URN) 9 digit numbers (no leading zeros).
I cannot think of a more efficient way to do this.

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 900000000 ) + 100000000 AS BIGINT)
```

The test used;

```
;WITH Fn(N) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 900000000 ) + 100000000 AS BIGINT)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 900000000 ) + 100000000 AS BIGINT)
    FROM Fn
)
,Tester AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5000000 *
    FROM Fn
)
SELECT   LEN(MIN(N))
        ,LEN(MAX(N)) 
        ,MIN(N)
        ,MAX(N)
FROM Tester
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I realised too late that the number needs to be unique.

Comment: There's no "too late" on SO. If you can figure out a good way to ensure uniqueness--mine's a bit kludgy--modify your answer!

Comment: I think my suggestion is as unique as the answer you chose(just double the speed)

Comment: I'm sorry they are not alike in their "uniqueness". Chosen solution seems to develop ~10500 duplicates per 500000 while my suggestion develops ~150 duplicates per 500000. There doesn't seem to be a simple way of guaranteeing a unique without a register or a wider number and playing the odds (as with a GUID). NOT a simple task :)

Answer (score 0):

Not so fast, but easiest... I added some dot's...

```
DECLARE @tr NVARCHAR(40)
SET @tr = CAST(ROUND((888*RAND()+111),0) AS CHAR(3)) + '.' + 
    CAST(ROUND((8888*RAND()+1111),0) AS CHAR(4)) + '.' + CAST(ROUND((8888*RAND()+1111),0) AS
    CHAR(4)) + '.' + CAST(ROUND((88*RAND()+11),0) AS CHAR(2))
PRINT @tr
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to obfuscate a database then this will return the same unique value for each distinct SSN in any table preserving referential integrity in the output without having to do a lookup and translate.

```
       SELECT CAST(RAND(SSN)*999999999 AS INT)
```